# red5 streaming server on GCP vm using red5pro-installer app not working with "sample" stream

Tags: google-cloud-platform, red5, red5pro

I have tried installing the red5pro streaming service on a vm with a trial account in google cloud platform.  I have used the red5pro-installer repo from github to do the "automatic" installation as well as tried installing everything manually.

When I use the installer, the web page works for me when I browse to my vm.  I am able to see my webcam's image on the "sample" stream page from the "broadcast" page of the vm.  I then enter a stream name and hit the "start broadcast" button and it starts to spin up then throws an error indicating "Publisher.Connection.Closed" (see attached image).
[image]

In looking at the logs on the VM, these two errors stand out:

> 2021-08-05 22:19:35,142 [https-jsse-nio2-0.0.0.0-443-exec-7] WARN  c.r.webrtc.stream.RTCSourceStream - ICE sockets not starting for: stream1
>
> 2021-08-05 22:19:35,141 [https-jsse-nio2-0.0.0.0-443-exec-7] INFO  com.red5pro.override.ProStream - Connection was null so cleanup is skipped

I have verified that all of the necessary ports are open for the correct traffic type on the GCP firewall to the VM.

I have also tried browsing to the vm via port 5080, and when I attempt to start a broadcast there, my webcam image is not showing and I see an error in the output window that says "no suitable publisher found".

Not sure where to turn next.

TIA